# I can’t seem to access my updated state from within this function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

I have this state:

```js
const [fingerprintingIssues, setFingerprintingIssues] = React.useState([])
```

I have a function that loops through a bunch of data to validate. If there are errors it adds them to `fingerprintingIssues` with `setFingerprintingIssues`. That works fine.

But in this method (abbreviated) I’m checking for `fingerprintingIssues` inside of the method’s `complete` and it always returns `[]`. I’ve read this is an issue with closures and stale state, but I can’t seem to see how that applies here.

```js
const validateDocument = data => {
    const start = moment()
    try {
        Papa.LocalChunkSize = 10485
        return Papa.parse(data, {
            complete: () => {
                // Log completion only if it’s been 20 seconds or more
                const end = moment()
                const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
                const seconds = Math.ceil(duration.asSeconds())
                if (seconds < MIN_PROCESS_TIME) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setUploadStep('tagging')
                        console.log('fingerprintingIssues', fingerprintingIssues)
                    }, (MIN_PROCESS_TIME - seconds) * 1000)
                } else {
                    setUploadStep('tagging')
                }
            },
            error: () => {
                setDocumentError(true)
                setDocumentReady(false)
            },
        })
        …
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think indeed it is an issue with closure and stale state. When using hooks, you need to be cautious about how you use callbacks.

Your component function is called many times (one for each render). Each call will receive a particular state. You can sort of think of it like that particular state is associated with that particular render. If you create a callback within your render, that callback will exist inside the closure of the render it was created in. The issue is that if your component is re-rendered, the callback still exists in the closure of the old render, and will not see the new state.

One way around this is to use React.useRef, which you can read more about [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). Refs hold a value and can be modified and accessed at any time regardless of closure. Note that modifying the ref does not cause your component to be re-rendered.

```
const fingerPrintingIssues = React.useRef([])
const validateDocument = data => {
    // Perform validation
    // Now access (refs are accessed by .current)
    console.log(fingerPrintingIssues.current)
}

// Modify:
fingerPrintingIssues.current.push(...)
```

In case you need to re-render your component when modifying the value, you can use combination of useRef() and useState().